# Content View me retorna un elemento en negro

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

Estoy tratando de crear una plantilla para usar múltiples veces en una vista, esta plantilla es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MYPROJECT.Resources.ViewElements.UserCard"
             x:Name="this">
    <Frame 
        BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding CardColor, FallbackValue='White'}"
        BorderColor="{Binding BorderColor, FallbackValue='White'}" >
        <Grid>
            <Frame BorderColor="{Binding BorderColorFrame, FallbackValue='White'}"
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding IconBackgroundColor , FallbackValue='White'}">
                <Image>
                    <Image.Source>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontSolid" Glyph="{Binding IconImageSource}" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Frame>
            <Label Text="{Binding CardTitle, FallbackValue='Card Title'}"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding BorderColorBox, FallbackValue='White'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding CardDescription, FallbackValue='Card description text.'}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

Realizo un binding de la siguiente manera:

```
public partial class UserCard : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CardTitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardTitle), typeof(string), typeof(UserCard), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty CardColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardColor), typeof(Brush), typeof(UserCard), Brush.Green);
    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Brush), typeof(UserCard), Brush.Green);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconBackgroundColor), typeof(Brush), typeof(UserCard), Brush.Green);
    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorFrameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColorFrame), typeof(Brush), typeof(UserCard), Brush.Green);
    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorBoxProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColorBox), typeof(Brush), typeof(UserCard), Brush.Green);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconImageSource), typeof(string), typeof(UserCard), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty CardDescriptionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardDescription), typeof(string), typeof(UserCard), string.Empty);
    
    public string CardTitle {
        get => (string)GetValue(UserCard.CardTitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.CardTitleProperty, value);
    }
    public Brush CardColor {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(UserCard.CardColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.CardColorProperty, value);
    }
    public Brush BorderColor {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(UserCard.BorderColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.BorderColorProperty, value);
    }
    public Brush BorderColorFrame
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(UserCard.BorderColorFrameProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.BorderColorFrameProperty, value);
    }

    public Brush BorderColorBox
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(UserCard.BorderColorBoxProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.BorderColorBoxProperty, value);
    }

    public Brush IconBackgroundColor {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(UserCard.IconBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.IconBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }
    public string IconImageSource {
        get => (string)GetValue(UserCard.IconImageSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.IconImageSourceProperty, value);
    }
    public string CardDescription {
        get => (string)GetValue(UserCard.IconImageSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(UserCard.IconImageSourceProperty, value);
    }
    public UserCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Y lo invoco en la vista principal a modo de prueba así:

```
UserCard userCard = new UserCard() {
            CardColor = Brush.Red,
            BorderColor = Brush.Yellow,
            IconBackgroundColor = Brush.Green,
            BorderColorFrame = Brush.Green,
            BorderColorBox = Brush.Green,
            IconImageSource = "&#xf533"
        };

container.Add(userCard);
```

El resultado que obtengo es un elemento de fondo negro, pero como se observa en el código yo jamás le pongo nada en negro, en la depuración accede a los setter con los valores que establezco en la vista principal, ¿Qué es lo que me sucede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Edición:
He descubierto que si quitamos el BoxView el negro desaparece y muestra todos los demás elementos, pero con los valores por defecto, es decir, no me recoge en mi declaración ninguna propiedad.

Comment: que es container ?? --> `container.Add(userCard);`

Comment: container es el nombre del  `FlexLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fondo negro es el valor `default` del `frame`, lo coloca porque te faltan elementos para que funcione el binding

**1.- Lo más importante es que te falta el `BindingContext` correcto.**

Tú tienes esto:

```
<Frame 
        BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Esto hace referencia a un template que no tienes. Se usa para cuando cuando está dentro de un `ControlTemplate`, generalmente cuando quieres pisar el template original.

Lo que deberías poner es:

```
<Frame 
       BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
```

A tu `ContentView` le agregaste el name `x:Name="this"`, entonces lo más fácil es referenciar el BindingContext por aquel nombre

**2.- Colores**

Creo que el tema de los colores tampoco debería funcionar, me parece que debes usar la clase `Color`, ejemplo:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CardColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CardColor), typeof(Color), typeof(UserCard), Colors.Green);

public Color CardColor
{
    get => (Color)GetValue(UserCard.CardColorProperty);
    set => SetValue(UserCard.CardColorProperty, value);
}
```

```
UserCard userCard = new UserCard()
{
   CardColor = Colors.Red,
   //etc
};
```

---

*Nota personal: Microsoft que manera de complicar los binding!!, además pasamos de `Inotifypropertychanged` a `BindableProperty` en vez de haberlo hecho de forma automática como se hace en Blazor*

Comment: *Respuesta a la nota: No veas que mareos genera*